# Are formulas in infinitary logic infinite strings?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I started reading [Karp](https://books.google.com/books/about/Languages_with_Expressions_of_Infinite_L.html?id=kOguAAAAIAAJ), and there, it seems that a formula in an infintary logic is a "string" of symbols in a given alphabet having certain properties, where by "string", we mean an $\alpha$-sequence of symbols, where $\alpha$ is an ordinal. Karp goes through great pains to carefully define the concatenation of these strings, the notion of a substring, and so on.

But in [Marker](https://books.google.com/books/about/Lectures_on_Infinitary_Model_Theory.html?id=78nxDAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description), after saying that the connectives, $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$, are in our alphabet, he goes on to say that if $X$ is a set of formulas, then
$$
\bigvee_{\phi\in X}\phi \text{ and } \bigwedge_{\phi\in X}\phi
$$
are formulas. But such an object is not even a "string" in the Karp sense. The symbols $\in$ and $X$, for instance, are not even in our alphabet. So what then are formulas, if not strings?

Looking at [Keisler](https://books.google.com/books?id=jdfuAAAAMAAJ&source=gbs_book_other_versions), I am guessing that a formula is what I might call, for lack of a better term, a "generalized string", by which I mean a finite sequence of objects, where each term in the sequence is either a symbol in our alphabet or a set of generalized strings. But if that is the case, then shouldn't more care be taken to ensure such a concept is well-defined, given the recursive nature of the definition? Also, if that is the case, then many of the notions from first-order logic, such as substring and subformula, need to be treated differently. And yet, Marker simply says, "We can inductively define the notions of free variable, subformula, sentence, theory and satisfiability in the usual ways." Finally, even if we carefully define everything, doesn't this different foundation make it difficult to cite results from Karp, since she constructs the fundamental objects in the subject in a completely different way?

Comment: Presumably Marker is assuming his audience is mathematically advanced enough to  find these details trivial.  This seems pretty reasonable for the level of the text.  There are many different ways to precisely formalize the definitions and it is clear that the exact details don't really matter for anything you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. To clarify, my question is not about Marker specifically. All the sources I've seen besides Karp have this same construction, and this same lack of commentary on what a formula is. Keisler is the exception, as he talks about it briefly, and that is why I mentioned "generalized strings" in my question.

Comment: Also, your comment seems to suggest that my question is simultaneously trivial and relatively unimportant. Unimportant would not be a surprise; I am often concerned with details of rigor that others might brush aside. As for trivial, I suppose that's relative. Hopefully, you're right, for if it is indeed trivial, then presumably someone will post an answer or I will be able to work it out myself. If I do, I will either post it as an answer or edit my question.